# What did "choice of gauge" mean?

Tags: gauge-theory, vector-fields

In a multivariable calculus exam I took many years ago, one problem gave us a certain vector field ${\bf F}$ on $\Bbb R^3$, first asked us to show that ${\rm div}({\bf F})=0$, and then to find ${\bf G}$ such that ${\rm curl}({\bf G})={\bf F}$. I argued that since any two fields with the same curl must differ by a gradient, we could assume that the first component of ${\bf G}$ was zero, because then we could make this first component whatever we wanted by adding a suitable gradient. And then I proceeded to solve the problem.

I got full marks and a puzzling comment from the professor, saying that I had made a "choice of gauge". Now I know one thing or another about principal bundles, so I guess my questions here are: what precisely could have he meant by a choice of gauge? What is the bundle? What is the structure group?

I would guess maybe the frame bundle of $T\Bbb R^3$ with structure group ${\rm GL}(3,\Bbb R)$ but this doesn't seem very enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

Re-posting my previous downvoted/deleted answer:

-->  *Assuming that the first component of $\mathbf{G}$ was zero amounts to a "choice of gauge."* <---

My answer was, and is, factually correct, and I hoped, helpful. Maybe I can add a bit:

When you say that "*the first component ... was zero,*" let me assume that by "*component*" you mean vector component (obvs, there are many other possible meanings to the word "*component*"), and when you say "*first component,*" you mean, e.g., the x-component in $(x,y,z)$ coordinates, and when you say, "*was zero*", you mean it was zero at some *point* $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, as opposed to, say, being zero *everywhere*.

Let $\mathbf{G}$ be a solution to $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{G} = \mathbf{F}$, and let $\mathbf{H} = \nabla \phi$ for some scalar field $\phi$. Then $\mathbf{G}'\equiv \mathbf{G} + \mathbf{H}$ is *also* a solution:
$$
\nabla \times \left( \mathbf{G} + \mathbf{H} \right) = \nabla \times \mathbf{G} = \mathbf{F}
$$
You could say, in linear algebra terms, that $\mathbf{H}$ is in the kernel of the linear map, from the vector space of $C^\infty$ vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto itself, that is induced by the linear operator $\nabla \times (\ \cdot\ ).\ $ A choice of $\mathbf{H}$ (or $\phi$) is a "choice of gauge."

Obviously, by suitable choice of gauge, you can make a component of $\mathbf{G}'$ equal to whatever you want it to be, at some given fixed point.

My previous answer was deleted because it "[didn't] appear to answer the question," and it "[didn't] meet the standard for this site." I thought it answered at least part of the question, and I do believe that it was better than all the other answers (read: none). I am happy to go back to my full-time job as a professional physicist if my posts keep getting deleted. Just trying to be helpful. Thanks.

I believe the poster has shown sufficient mathematical sophistication to take my answer and figure out what the *frame bundle* and the *structure group* are; I'm not going to try, since it's been over thirty years since I studied topology.

-PTW

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What you explained is exactly what I had in mind when I took that exam. The point of the question was exactly to understand precisely what he meant by "gauge" and the hidden bundle structures.